# scaling font with media query works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using `media query` to scale the font size as the window shrinks. I assign width & height values with `rem` unit to my containers.

When i open dev tools and resize the window everything works as expected. But on my mobile phone the design is broken.

Tested on Iphone 7 plus and Iphone xr using Safari and chrome.

Here is an example:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 30rem);
  gap: 4rem 10rem;
  grid-auto-rows: 30rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 60%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  html {
    font-size: 40%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  html {
    font-size: 30%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  html {
    font-size: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=17" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the percentages my self and using pixels solved the problem. Still not sure why wouldn't it work on mobile while working completely fine on desktop.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  html {
    font-size: 6px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  html {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 3px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  html {
    font-size: 2px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using rem to specify the sizes maybe this piece of code is causing the issue

```
**body {
  height: 100vh;
}**
```

Again I checked your code in Dev Tools everything worked fine not sure, why the design is breaking on a mobile device, you can try specifying the height in rem only.

Comment: it did not help unfortunately

Comment: Please try to post only solution to the question with proper explanation , and try to avoid question specific to user , add them in comments